# Bringing ASP.NET Website Admin Tool functionality to webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, active-directory

I am using VS2005 .NET 2.0 C#.

I am currently managing my user roles by the build in ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool, managing users etc, as well as using ActiveDirectory authentication

I have 2 questions.

---

**Firstly**, is there any sample code which I can refer to on the web in order to implement the role editing of the ASP.NET Website Admin Tool onto my webpage? The GUI need not be there, I only require the *username* and the role checkboxes on my webpage.

[image]
Working code examples will be appreciated

---

**Secondly**, I have been receiving an error when I tried to create a new user after I have changed my authentication from *Web* to *Windows*, which uses ActiveDirectory. Below is the error:

[image]

Is it because *AD* does not allow creating of new users or is it because the account I provided in my `connectionUsername` and `connectionPassword` in the *web.config* does not have sufficient privilege?

---

**EDIT:**

For my **first** question, I have a button which loads the user role from a database.

[image]

Below is the method:

```
protected void loadUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AdminCb.Checked = false;
    UserCb.Checked = false;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TP;Initial Catalog=MP;User ID=user;Password=password");
    string sql = "SELECT [User Type] FROM [UserRoles] where [Name]=@Name";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = UserNameList.Text;
    conn.Open();
    Object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();

    if (result != null)
    {
        string usertype = result.ToString();
        if (usertype == "Super User")
        {
            AdminCb.Checked = true;
        }
        if (usertype == "Normal User")
        {
            UserCb.Checked = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Is it possible for me to retrieve the list of users from ActiveDirectory and implement it similar to my method above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As for your first question, the *Website Admin Tool* is simply a web interface that sits on top of the **Membership API**.  In other words, if you click something like "add a new role" on the *Web Admin Tool*, you're basically calling [`Roles.CreateRole()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.createrole.aspx).

How you want to design **your** web interface is up to you.  But to utilize the complete functionality of the *Website Admin Tool*, you need to implement many of the classes in [`System.Web.Security`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt5ssstk.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Thank you for the structure breakdown of the tool. May I know if it is possible to call `Roles.CreateRole()` method, and any other methods such as revoke user from a specific role on my *.asp* webpage and assign it to a button_click?

Comment: @RUiHAO Are you using ASP.NET or classic ASP?  I can only speak on behalf of ASP.NET, but in that case yes.  When you call the static `Roles.CreateRole()` method, your application will be utilizing the `roleManager` from your *web.config* file to access the underlying membership data store (i.e. database) to add the role.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET. Are there any guides on the net which provide list of methods which the tool is using?

Comment: @RUiHAO Absolutely.  Check out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.aspx.  It is for the `System.Web.Security` namespace.  You'll mostly be concerned with the `Membership` and `Roles` class listed there.

Comment: the `Roles` class is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you